# Get column datatype, sort direction onload, change sort order on first click of header in tablesorter

Tags: client-side, tablesorter, gridview-sorting

I have a grid view, which has several columns, one of which is a numeric column. When the grid loads first time, the data on the numeric column gets sorted on the server side itself and gets rendered. I apply client side sorting on another column also using table sorter. Now, the requirement is, because the number column comes already sorted in ascending order, upon clicking the number column header should sort it in descending order first. How can I achieve this? I thought of doing it in the following way, but getting no help.
1. How to find out the data type of a column by giving column or index using table sorter?
2. Identify whether a column is already sorted on load and if so, the sort direction of a that column.
3. Sort that column (mentioned above) in descending order, upon first time header click of that column.

I did try with debug option of table sorter, but it is simply giving some alert message, which is not much helpful.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Set the initial sort order in tablesorter to be the same as what is returned back from the server. For example, say your numeric column is column zero and you are returning it back from the server in desc order. Use the following in the table sorter config:

```
sortList:[[0,1]]
```

This will tell tablesorter to sort the first column in descending order. Now that tablesorter knows how the data is sorted, the next time you click on this column to sort it, it will sort in ascending order (since it's currently sorted in descending order).

Comment: If I do that, then the sort image appears, which I don't want, as I have to do this for some other column and also, the data comes sorted from the server. Moreover, I would like to know, how to identify the column type and also want to identify, whether a column is already sorted when the screen loads. Also, without setting the initial sort order, upon first time click, I want to able to sort this column in the opposite direction compared to other columns, for which, I would need answers for my first 2 questions.